# Polymer 1.0 notifyPath for array element

Tags: polymer

Simple example:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.subitems}}">
        <span>{{item}}</span>
    </template>
    <span on-tap="add">ADD</span>
</template>

attached: function () {
    this.items = [
        { subitems:[] },
        { subitems:[] }
    ]
},
add: function (e) {
    e.model.item.subitems.push("Test");
}
```

This will not refresh the dom-repeat for {{item.subitems}}. How can I notify polymer of the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat)

> Mutations to the items array itself (push, pop, splice, shift, unshift) must be performed using methods provided on Polymer elements, such that the changes are observable to any elements bound to the same array in the tree. For example: `this.push('employees', { first: 'Jack', last: 'Aubrey' });`

Comment: I think this only works for pushing an element to items, but not to subitems.

Comment: Bit hacky, but I've managed to do it like:
`var arrayLoc = e.model.__key__;`
`var stringLoc = "items." + arrayLoc + ".subitems";`
`this.push(stringLoc, "test");`

Comment: I am sorry I have tried this and it does not work: this.push("item.subitems", "Test"). I think it might be possible by using the index of the element like this "items.3.subitems" but there must be a simpler way?

Comment: After some testing I think the correct way of doing this is: e.model.push("item.subitems", "Test")